# Delete where email is not a known email client

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to delete records from a table that is getting to much spam. So, the idea is delete all records that don't have email from hotmail, gmail or yahoo. But my sql looks like is returning some hotmail records:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE email NOT LIKE '*hotmail.com*'
AND email NOT LIKE '*gmail.com*'
AND email NOT LIKE '*ymail.com*'
```

Applying the `OR` condition returns the same result. Can you guide to the right direction?

Comment: Do the ones passing through use exactly hotmail.com, or are they using something very close to it like hotmail.co?

Comment: Mmm, good point. It should be able to keep hotmail.co and hotmail.com :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query should look like this

```
SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE email NOT LIKE '%hotmail.com%'
AND email NOT LIKE '%gmail.com%'
AND email NOT LIKE '%ymail.com%'
```

You have to replace `*` by `%`

> If SQL LIKE clause is used along with % characters then it will work
>   like a meta character (*) in Unix while listing out all the files or
>   directories at command prompt.

[Here's](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-like-clause.htm) the doc about LIKE in MySQL

Comment: Thank you so much :) I keep in my the `%` as placeholder

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    users
WHERE   email NOT RLIKE '\\@(hotmail|gmail|ymail)\\.com$'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query will also return you gmail and ymail

In mysql you have to use % instead of *

So just substitute it and everything will be ok.